# How to bind to a property of the ViewModel from within a GridView

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, mvvm

I'm using the MVVM design pattern, and the `DataContext` of my View is set to a ViewModel.

In my View, I have a `ListView/GridView` with `ItemsSource` bound to a `DataTable`. One of the `GridViewColumns` has a `CellTemplate` that presents a `Button`. I want the `IsEnabled` property of the button to be bound to the `SelectButtonsEnabled` property of my ViewModel.

Using `IsEnabled="{Binding Path=SelectButtonsEnabled}"` doesn't work because my `DataTable` doesn't have a column named "SelectButtonsEnabled". The property I'm trying to bind to is global for the whole ViewModel, not specific to a row of the `DataTable`.

I think I need some kind of `RelativeSource` tag, but all my attempts thus far have failed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this is the most succinct way to do it, but this works:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.SelectButtonsEnabled}"
```