# How to use a Binding of the ViewModel instead of the DataType of a ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, mvvm, uwp

Let me begin with apologizing for the perhaps somewhat vague title, I'm having a hard time explaining my problem! Perhaps this is why I'm hardly getting any Google results, with this post being the closest to my problem (I think): [How to bind to a property of the ViewModel from within a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338848/how-to-bind-to-a-property-of-the-viewmodel-from-within-a-gridview)

Anyways, I have a list of news articles that are being dynamically generated. The user has the option to press a "Star"-button in order to add an article to his/her favorites list. This "Star"-button should thus only be visible when the user is logged in.

I'm trying to achieve this by setting the Visibility of the Button to a property called IsLoggedIn inside my ViewModel. However, because this is happening inside my ListView it's trying to find the property IsLoggedIn inside of Article instead of the ViewModel.

So I guess my questions boils down to: How can I bind to a ViewModel property inside of a Databound ListView?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind VM.Articles, Mode=OneWay}" ItemClick="DebuggableListView_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="None" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Article">
            <Grid Margin="0,10,10,10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed"/>
                <Button Visibility="{x:Bind VM.IsLoggedIn, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE734;" FontSize="30" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Summary}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Requested Article class:**

```
public sealed class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Feed { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string[] Related { get; set; }
    public Category[] Categories { get; set; }
    public bool IsLiked { get; set; }
}
```

Okay, so currently I got it working by having a property which gets the singleton of my VM, however I'm sure there has to be a cleaner way to get something simple like this working. I've added a sample rar (OneDrive link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar4fOTiwmGYnyWbwRY6rM0eFsL9x) which has a list, a ViewModel, some dummy data and a Visibility property inside the VM. If you can get it working without my dirty method please feel free to commit as an answer.

Comment: Did you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32862922/424129)?

Comment: Can you update your Question with `Articles` Class

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm guessing  you're referring to the last piece of code in that answer? Attempting to get that part working in my case atm.

Comment: @AVKNaidu I added the Article class, didn't think a model would help much.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have a setup at work here to compile UWP projects, but I think he's saying you should be able to expose your DataContext as a `VM` property on the codebehind and use the `x:Bind` binding you have -- unless I misunderstand.

Comment: Or perhaps something like [this](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)

Comment: @EdPlunkett Hm, I tried it and it doesn't seem to work in my case. Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Added a OneDrive link with a sample solution which has the same kind of structure as I have but without any of the other functionalities.

Comment: User Logged In Status is app level or in this case Page Level but not article level. Only thing is additional functionality of Showing / Hiding Favourite Button based on Login Status. In this case, i would suggest not to complicate the VM and create a Public Boolean Property on the page, Populate the value based on LoginStatus and Bind Relative Source for Page as Self so that you can use that property to Bind to Button. Let me know if you want me to post an answer with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

This type problem can best be solved using relative binding. Rather than binding directly to the current DataContext, i.e. this case the individual item in the ListView's ItemsSource, you can bind to a property of any ancestor element.

Given a simple ViewModel class

```
public class ViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isLoggedIn;
    public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get { return _isLoggedIn; }
        set
        {
            _isLoggedIn = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsLoggedIn);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Items
    { get { return new[] {"One", "Two", "Theee", "Four", "Five"}; } }
}
```

the View can then be defined as

```
<Window x:Class="ParentBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ParentBindingTest"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="300" Height="400">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CheckBox Margin="16,8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Logged In?" IsChecked="{Binding IsLoggedIn, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="16,8" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsLoggedIn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <Image Source="Images\remove.png" />
                        </Button>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note how in the item DataTemplate, the TextBlock's Text property is bound directly to the item.

However the Button's Visibility is bound not to a propery of it's own DataContext, but to that of the ListView itself, using relative binding.

Comment: Does this work on a List of non-primitive types? (in my case Article instead of string)

Comment: "The member AncestorType is not recognized as or is not accessible", I'm guessing that this only works in WPF but not on UWP

Comment: I don't have windows 10 where I am right now, so I can't test it, but the accepted answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861612 seems to have the answer for UWP - naming the ListView control and the binding via ElementName

Comment: So it turns out x:Bind is being the problem for what I need. Using a traditional binding along with using the ListView ElementName fixes it. If you update  your answer to reflect this I can accept it as an answer.